# How to stay safe when adding new apt keys?

Tags: apt, security, repository, malware, signature

I'm a new user to Linux.

I want to know how to stay safe when adding and installing new software by adding apt keys to repository then running `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install name`.

On Windows I scan with VirusTotal and run sandboxed/offline to ensure the safety of unknown sources.

How can I do this on Ubuntu even when adding unsigned keys?

Comment: Stay safe against what? What's the threat vector here? MITM of the keyserver?